# Drawing shapes on inkcanvas

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, shapes

I'm gerenerally new to coding and i would like to seek some help to guide me about how to make a drawable triangle on the inkcanvas. I've created a button. Upon clicking on the button, i'm supposed to click in the inkcanvas and drag to form the triangle. (Work the same as any shapes to be drawn on the paint application in windows and microsoft words.)

I'm quite lost about how to go about doing this as i need to do a few other random shapes as well. I was hoping to be able to know how to create a triangle and use that knowledge i get from here to try to do the remaining other shapes that i will be doing.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You can use mouse click event to catch the points -> Class: Point(x,y);
Then you can use DrawLine() to draw line between two Points.

E.g

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics; 
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red); 
Point p1 = new Point(50,50); 
Point p2 = new Point(1,1); 
g.DrawLine(p, p1, p2); 
g.Dispose();
```

Here are two good examples:

1. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Drawing_Graphics_in_C_Sharp
2. http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/Drawshapestothebitmapinmemory.htm